# 'demand' of static method is not working with 'new MockFor' in Grails-3.2.4 'Junit Testing'

Tags: grails, junit, grails-3.0, grails3.2.0

Can anyone please let me know how to demand static methods of a class. 
I have tried with below code & it's not working with it:

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor

final mockCl = new MockFor(ClassName) 
mockCl.demand.static.methodName(1) { return 'something' }
```

With this it's giving below exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: static for   class: groovy.mock.interceptor.Demand at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:87)
```

Can someone point me how to mock static methods in JUNIT with grails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
YourClass.metaClass.static.methodName = { return 'something }
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for the reply it's working with :
YourClass.metaClass.static.methodName = { return 'something }

Please edit your answer then I will accept it as a reply.